# drush 8.1.9 on php 7 not giving any "drush status" in docroot folder

Tags: 7, drush

I just setup a fresh install of drupal 7, ubuntu 16.04, installed php 7.0 and git cloned the drush repo which checkout of 8.1.9 drush. When I do a drush status on the docroot of my drupal folder it shows the following and when doing a drush dl it fetches only drupal 8 modules.

```
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1.12
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :  /home/ubuntu/.drush/hotsite.aliases.drushrc.php
```

[image]

When I used to run php 5.6, it would give me all the details of my install. What did I do wrong here?

---- updated with drush status in the sites/default folder:

```
$:/var/www/hotsite_d7/docroot/sites/default$ drush status
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1.12
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :  /home/ubuntu/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php

$/var/www/hotsite_d7/docroot/sites/default$ drush @hotsite status
 Drupal version                  :  7.57-dev
 Site URI                        :  http://default
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database hostname               :  127.0.0.1
 Database port                   :
 Database username               :  xxx
 Database name                   :  xxx
 Database                        :  Connected
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :
 Default theme                   :  bootstrap
 Administration theme            :  seven
 PHP executable                  :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                          :  Linux
 Drush script                    :  /vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version                   :  8.1.12
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp
 Drush configuration             :
 Drush alias files               :  /home/ubuntu/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php
 Install profile                 :  standard
 Drupal root                     :  /var/www/hotsite_d7/docroot
 Drupal Settings File            :  sites/default/settings.php
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp

$/var/www/hotsite_d7/docroot/sites/default$
```

Comment: You write that it works if you use ```drush @mysite status```. Could you add the output above?

Comment: it looks like this when doing drush status: http://prntscr.com/g3wh7y

Comment: Thx. Still a mystery. Please also post the content of the hotsite alias. And maybe the output of `drush status --debug`

Answer (score 1):

Drush usually does this when it cannot find a Drupal installation, which happens when it cannot find a `settings.php`. Did you go through the installation process yet? (visiting `install.php` on the browser or doing `drush site-install`)

Comment: yes i installed it and its verified working. i am however able to drush the site when i do it via alias like this: "drush @mysite status" --- why wouldn't drush detect the directory? i'm in it.

Comment: @duckx it's been that way for a while now, not sure which release of drush it changed in exactly. You need to be in sites/site_name or use an alias these days

Comment: @Clive when doing a drush status in sites/default i dont get the status output neither, but works with an alias. I have drush 8.1.9 -- see: http://prntscr.com/g3wh7y